# Understand Finder Find Results

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight, search

I am looking in a folder for a file which contains `path` in its name. I enter `path` in the search box, and select it to search the current folder (which is my default anyway). The tool tip indicates `Filenames` `Name matches: path`.

What I see is 110 items, none of which even contain the string `path`, let alone match.

[image]

What does the finder think I am looking for, and what do the results actually mean?

This is a relatively new iMac running MacOS Sierra.

Comment: Picture of the search might help [suitably anonymised in photoshop if needs be]. A lot depends on where the search is & how finely the parameters are specified. If you actually need 'hard' searching then Spotlight is not the best tool; it's a bit too 'user friendly'. There are alternatives, command line or UI-based. If you can edit your question to clarify, answers will be easier to provide.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have added an image. I am aware of other tools, which I do use regularly. The question is what do the results mean?

Answer (score 1):

1. In the Finder, use command-F to get a Finder search window.  You will get:

   [image]
2. There is now a bar with criteria added.  You see a pop-up menu "Kind" followed by "is" and another pop-up menu "Any".  Click the "Kind", and choose "Name" from that menu:

   [image]
3. There now is a pop-up menu just following "Name", select "contains" from that, and type the word "path" in the field that follows.
4. You can add criteria by clicking the + sign at the right of the search bar.

Spotlight does seem to "power" the default search field in Finder windows.  I use Spotlight only in desperation, as it almost never ever finds what I'm looking for.  But with the search criteria in the Finder's search window I usually book success.

So, remember:  command-F gets you a Finder search window with a criteria bar, and that certainly helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here: by default, Finder will:

- search the contents of files as well as their names
- search either your entire Mac hard disk, or the current folder *and* all its subfolders.

To solve the first problem, you need to to tell Finder just to match filenames. When you typed "path" into the search box, a dropdown menu should have appeared, with the option "Name matches: path". Select that, instead of just pressing Enter. Alternatively, you can type `name:path` into the search box, which has the same effect.

You can't really solve the second problem with Finder; even when restricting the search to the current folder, there is no way to exclude its sub-folders. For that, you'll need a third-party tool, or learn to use commands in the Terminal like `ls *path*`.

Comment: As you see in the screen capture, a particular folder was selected. The question is why do all of those results appear which do _not_ contain the search string `path`?

Comment: Yes, sorry: just re-edited answer to cover that.

Comment: I already had `Name matches: path`, but I didn’t know about the `name:path` technique. It didn’t help either.

Comment: Ok... you didn't have 'name matches path' selected in your screenshot, as that would [look like this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1802478/stackexchange-spotlight.png). But if you're doing that now, I don't have any other ideas :/

Answer (score 0):

You can also add criteria to the pop-up list.  A useful one is the file extension.  E.g. here is the result for a search for all files that are images with file extension jpeg (not jpg) opened in the last 3 weeks:
[image]